# sorting columns from lowest to highest values (i.e. 1, 2, 3 etc, not 1, 10, 11...2, 20, 21... etc)

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 50 thousand rows that I want to sort according the the values in one of the columns. The numbers in the column go from 1-30, and when I do the following

```
 data=data[order(data$columnname),]
```

it gets sorted so that the order of the columns is like this

1, 10, 11 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 2, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 3, 30, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

how could I sort it so that it is like this

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30

Comment: Try `data[order(as.numeric(data$columnname)),]`

Comment: oh sorry @akrun ! I just have 0s  and 1s as values in the column

Comment: Then, where does this `1, 10, 11, 12, 13, etc.` comes from?

Comment: so it's exactly the same as what I initially posted, I just forgot to add that the values go from 0 - 30 rather than 1-30

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output as it is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

For me it seems, that your format is not numeric. Try this:

```
data$columnname<-as.numeric(data$columnname)
data=data[order(data$columnname),]
```

Comment: thanks, that worked but for some reason the 0s and 1s are mixed up, so it looks like

0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 ...etc and then 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,  4, 4, 4,  etc as normal. Any idea why?

Comment: Thats weird, does **data$columnname<-as.numeric(as.character(data$columnname))** help?